# Get Image from path

Tags: java, android

I want to get Image from Album , but when I pick any picture it don't show and stop. I test with my phone , I think the problem is maybe I set the wrong path with my code . But I can't find where it is.
case 100 : take picture action and it can work , case 101 : pick picture action.

This is my onActivityResult

```
protected  void **onActivityResult**(int requestCode , int resultCode ,  Intent 
data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK ) {
            switch (requestCode)
            {
                case 100:
                    Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                    sendBroadcast(it);
                    break;
                case 101:
                    imgUri = convertUri(data.getData());

                    break;
            }
        showImg();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this , requestCode==100? "no take the pic" : "no choose the pic" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

This is my converUri

```
Uri convertUri(Uri uri){
    if(uri.toString().substring(0,7).equals("content"))
    {
        String[] colName = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri,colName,null,null,null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        uri = Uri.parse("file://"+ cursor.getString(0));
    }
    return  uri;
}
```

This is my showImag

```
void showImg(){
    imv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    int  iw ,ih , vw, vh;
    boolean needRotate;
    BitmapFactory.Options option = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    option.inJustDecodeBounds =  true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgUri.getPath(),option);

    iw = option.outWidth;
    ih = option.outHeight;
    vw = imv.getWidth();
    vh = imv.getHeight();

    int scaleFactor;
    if(iw<ih)
    {
        needRotate = false;
        scaleFactor = Math.min(iw/vw , ih/vh);
    }else{
        needRotate = true ;
        scaleFactor =Math.min( ih / vw , iw/vh);
    }
    option.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    option.inSampleSize = scaleFactor ;
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgUri.getPath(),option);
    if(needRotate)
    {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(90);
        bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp , 0 , 0 ,bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix , true);
    }
    imv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the wrong way with trying to get a file system path.

Better use the data.getData() uri from onActivityResult dirtectly.

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgUri.getPath(),option);
```

Change to:

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, option);
```

Do the same for the first call. You can use `is` only once.

Comment: thks for your ans , but It cannot work . When I pick , it stopped. is it something wrong with my convertUri or my phone or uses-permission.